# c# Nmodbus how to tcp slave

Tags: c#, modbus

I'm converting a project from [NModbus4](https://github.com/NModbus4/NModbus4) to [NModbus](https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus) (since NModbus4 has last commit 5 years ago) but I can't find any modbus slave tcp implementation example so I'm stuck to this code and don't know how to get further. I'm searching for a solution all morning but

```
    applicationLog.Info("Initializing modbus slave");
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 }), Properties.Settings.Default.TcpModbusPort);
    modbusSlave = modbusFactory.CreateSlave(1, new SlaveDataStore());
    modbusSlaveTransport = modbusFactory.CreateSlaveNetwork(tcpListener);
    applicationLog.Info("Modbus slave listening on port " + Properties.Settings.Default.TcpModbusPort);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this package I've managed to connect to Modbus RTU<->TCP converter that communicates with measuring device:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NModbus/

Here you have some code samples that may be helpful (Especially from line 466):

https://github.com/NModbus/NModbus/blob/master/Samples/Program.cs

I have tested one method for reading holding registers (but as master) and it seems to be working.

Comment: That page definitely deserved to be of more easy access, I wasted an entire morning searching for something like this.
I really have to thank you!